# Isomorphism as $R$-module

Tags: modules

Let $R = M_2(\mathbb{C})\times M_2(\mathbb{C})$ and let
\begin{equation*}
e_1 = \left( \begin{bmatrix}
       1 & 0 \\
       0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix}
       0 & 0 \\
       0 & 0
\end{bmatrix} \right),~~ 
e_2 = \left( \begin{bmatrix}
       0 & 0 \\
       0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix}
       0 & 0 \\
       0 & 0
\end{bmatrix} \right),~~ 
e_3 = \left( \begin{bmatrix}
       0 & 0 \\
       0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix}
       1 & 0 \\
       0 & 0
\end{bmatrix} \right),
\end{equation*}
Prove that, as $R$-module, $Re_1$ is isomorphic to $Re_2$ but is not isomorphic to $Re_3.$

What I did is
\begin{equation}
 Re_1 = \begin{bmatrix}
       a_1 & b_1 \\
       c_1 & d_1
\end{bmatrix} \cdot 
\begin{bmatrix}
       1 & 0 \\
       0 & 0
\end{bmatrix} + 
\begin{bmatrix}
       a_2 & b_2 \\
       c_2 & d_2
\end{bmatrix} \cdot 
\begin{bmatrix}
       0 & 0 \\
       0 & 0
\end{bmatrix} = 
\left( \begin{bmatrix}
       a_1 & 0 \\
       c_1 & 0
\end{bmatrix} , \begin{bmatrix}
       0 & 0 \\
       0 & 0
\end{bmatrix} \right)
\end{equation}
Similarly,
\begin{equation}
Re_2 = \left( \begin{bmatrix}
       0 & b_2 \\
       0 & d_2
\end{bmatrix} , \begin{bmatrix}
       0 & 0 \\
       0 & 0
\end{bmatrix} \right) , \quad
Re_3 =\left( \begin{bmatrix}
       0 & 0 \\
       0 & 0
\end{bmatrix} , \begin{bmatrix}
       a_3 & 0 \\
       c_3 & 0
\end{bmatrix} \right)
\end{equation}

I dont see why $Re_1 \cong Re_2$ and why $Re_1, Re_2 \not\cong Re_3$ as $R$-module. What would be the isomorphism in first case? Thanks in advance for any kind of help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see the answer by thinking of each $R$-module as $\mathbb C^2$ with a particular $R$-action.  If you write $(x,y)$ for an element, you can calculate that the $R$-action is
\begin{equation}
 \left(\begin{bmatrix}
       a_1 & b_1 \\
       c_1 & d_1
\end{bmatrix}, 
\begin{bmatrix}
       a_2 & b_2 \\
       c_2 & d_2
\end{bmatrix}\right) \cdot
(x,y) = (a_1x+b_1y,c_1x+d_1y)
\end{equation}
for $Re_1$ and $Re_2$. So an isomorphism between those modules would identify $\left( \begin{bmatrix}
       x & 0 \\
       y & 0
\end{bmatrix} , \begin{bmatrix}
       0 & 0 \\
       0 & 0
\end{bmatrix} \right)$ with $\left( \begin{bmatrix}
       0 & x \\
       0 & y
\end{bmatrix} , \begin{bmatrix}
       0 & 0 \\
       0 & 0
\end{bmatrix} \right)$.  But for $Re_3$, the action is
\begin{equation}
 \left(\begin{bmatrix}
       a_1 & b_1 \\
       c_1 & d_1
\end{bmatrix}, 
\begin{bmatrix}
       a_2 & b_2 \\
       c_2 & d_2
\end{bmatrix}\right) \cdot
(x,y) = (a_2x+b_2y,c_2x+d_2y).
\end{equation}
I'll leave it to you to think about how to turn this into a proof that an isomorphism does not exist between this module and the other two.